# Cannot install Tensorflow with Anaconda Navigator

Tags: tensorflow, installation, anaconda, conda, python-3.11

Installed Anaconda Navigator this morning, created and activated new Python environment called tf.

Tried to add Tensorflow using Conda and get this error message:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgMsw.png)

Have tried to install it via the GUI as well, but doesn't seem to work either -- finishes the process, no error messages thrown up, but Tensorflow still not installed??

Initially was trying using Python 3.11 but that was throwing up a different error message complaining that 3.11 wasn't supporting Tensorflow, got around that by dropping to 3.10 but now this!

I don't have full admin rights on this machine so not sure if that is causing the issue as well.

Very new to this so any ideas greatfully received!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the mentioned file as your erro message suggests?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the .conda archive and tried again; the `tensorflow-base-2.10.0-mkl_py310h6a7f48e_0` directory shows up briefly midway through the install, then vanishes just before the error message is displayed.

Comment: Managed to briefly access the directory `tensorflow-base-2.10.0-mkl_py310h6a7f48e_0` directory mid-install, but then got thrown out again after a few seconds and the filepath was broken -- it's like its being deleted mid-install when it shouldn't be?

Comment: Hi @bast.ion, You don't have admin rights to the drive which could be the reason for not be able to download and install the package. You can try using [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/?utm_source=scs-index), where you can install any package to use.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. It is due to the default character limit in Windows. Go to Windows Start and type `regedit`. Set the `DWORD` parameter named `LongPathsEnabled` under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` to 1 and reboot.

Check this article for exact details: https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/The-Windows-10-default-path-length-limitation-MAX-PATH-is-256-characters.html

Comment: It is a correct answer, but the OP has no admin rights. I'm afraid they're in the cold.